# Binary format error while saving image to a folder in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to save an image on the local server, it is saving without error.

But when i try to save on server its giving a binary format error.

I have changed the folder path where it's saving from `"EmpImages/+filename+";` to `"~/Admin/EmpImages/+filename+";` but this doesn't help.

```
��Y�o�8�����^\�`m��ĉ����@�@�X�%Ѷ6���-z�͐��WR���.pZ[�'��͟�\���鐱������L?  �5ǌ��ws��V��RD�ǌ�T��+�>� �z�����{�F>\:��c�c_xj����:Q܍舩A�v�)�����+(�30�i��%�Ӕp���$`�XH�#���q}�����lx�`.r��,��|����C(i��z�=�>�4�0w�,�u����R�'V'N�E O�B�ݐz�/d  7~�2HD�(�-�:)ų/˶�����L>�op�|�T�d>Y��|#�a    �WPc�֜?\���\>�.��{���S�-×ކ�^j���>���#HbpV[�Ќe��<0�*O�'&��ZKl�5���/  ���t��!L�;ŴNh�E�Lǁf��: ���p[H�|�HJF xc՞�m;�}Ŷʉ��    �fq� �Ŕ��K��Ȅ���eO3p����V�I�阜��*�"�8���i����\*��`���m��T�l�Y� �J�4���A�PS�c�`��!��,ז �䂁��̓1�&��Kx�rU�e�$�2O^)&�!�B�E�0�pۭ�,��6' �R �p��c�T1r��H��&lƼ�>�f    �9e.��cvĉ*��G�2�a#-��9�D*'�C�*G]�h��$�o:f�J!شT�-�l�V���t� ��9���zm.�u�7W�E��}45��os����Q0�Ʒ{7�U��ϸ���.4�����"�p_2%�1��t���5�,�HS����Be I���ɞ��"����X �XD��<��Ch�����U��Q�����d�\1 ��@p���xvlR��jy�զ��Q��G�5���5����Ɛ% kĖ�d� ��Q(%�CHw�ʕUd���F���1;�����2a�[qo�y���aH\f5A�G"1����u�z��i��ڗ���� @$��d���R���y�1�-%� dy[}0�x��[���b�F�ፅ�4[wn�_u���6 R,d�ݫ=`�>j�B�l���������8 P�f���*��!`]��T$x!�maxc���S�G� 6^`*Ÿ�<�=[��m�q�?M�LK=$kN?���r�U   #$7o������2Y� ����fr|T���+{t�2Li��ZV�0���3�� Q� }c�� {��9�O�0T1c�b��_�x������Fa|5h@ə�d�ao�z�6��L7�ņ����ڷ�۹�� ���up�H�@CU,��7�����ڦ���ktw�.��%�6���f�$h�>���e����z�R�ۻUZ��5m�"/h80��{�T�3�S���]7�����B�vn�=����������/��{?WOߣ���~���8�.�����!�C�����~��j�N;��Lrv�FtI���,WN�˕ã5D� �`�x��Sit+o �@a�Bd�L��$�'V����54VF9��mz���)` �_H��p�dl�\��*"�'x�9�����o�����w�N:���Z�G����P쾕"�n3���N \�!2����Aq< A~aT��鯺����Z?Z���u.�8o΀�6c�G�G���uɻ.~�����1d��7@*���G�q5?4�7�������M9O:]�r�`���Gh�~��5G^'�Zϝkn�Y���i��r|z��- ���38���4��S�ZxS������%_��\٢��i�Veľ�ffE��h[ПRt��   ��8%ک]�7TS��>�uc_+n�x{I���D��ć�������:�ލp4ܺ�=�L>�B7���8Z�IM��[���T����l�m㗁'�CM̬�VB��V*V?tJN�T-CgZԏ�jN�rRqJj����hϭ��� �|����6[c)��}�v�   ��g� �_���!cץw�[_�bf� �w����L��Yx�f�3���ە~��2=���g�����n���)�r'x    2��q�/IʈY1"
```

The above binary format is coming when I am uploading the image.

And below is the code where image is getting saved on button click:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileImgUpload.PostedFile.FileName);
string file_path = "~/Admin/EmpImages/" + id.ToString() + filename;
fileImgUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(file_path));
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: images - like any file - *are* binary, so... it isn't obvious whether we should be overly concerned here. Is it writing something to disk? Do the bytes match what was uploaded? (note: allowing users to upload arbitrary files to your server may be a bad idea)

Comment: just saving image to folder mentioned above and path to the database. I think when image is saving to folder getting error like this. what to do for this issue.

Comment: "error like this"...what error? You haven't mentioned an error message. You've just shown us some data, which looks very like what a binary file might look like if you open it in a text editor. I'm not sure what you are trying to demonstrate to us by showing it. Where did you see this data? Does the file actually get saved to your server? Can you open the saved file in an image viewer, or not? Or does your code throw some other kind of exception? It's really not clear what the actual problem is.

Comment: Its directly showing "some data" when i update the image. No it is not saving in to the server nor i can view the image. No exception is there that is why i cannot explain in detail.

Comment: "Its directly showing" ...**what** is directly showing? You mean you see that code directly in the browser window? We don't know how that got there because you haven't shown us any code except for a couple of lines where you try to save the file. We have no idea what the rest of your code does, or how it might end up doing that. You'd have to add more information.

Comment: if (fileImgUpload.HasFile)
 {
 string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileImgUpload.PostedFile.FileName);                
 string file_path = "~/Admin/EmpImages/" + id.ToString() + filename;
 fileImgUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(file_path));       
}

Comment: ??? You've already shown us that code, apart from the `if` part. That doesn't explain or answer anything from my previous comment. It's going to be hard to help you if you can't/won't answer questions clearly and in detail. P.S. Also if you have code to show, please don't put it into comments, instead use the "edit"  button under your question to add it to the main text, and format it properly to be readable - thankyou.